# Wordpress Connection was Reset? Error 101

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm using `Wordpress MU` to host two wordpress sites. All of a sudden both the sites are down.

I remember adding a few plugins yesterday and I modified the `page.php` of the responsiveness theme. I made a backup so now I changed page.php back to it' original.

All the other sites I am hosting work, I host a webail client and a web application and they are working fine so it's not a problem with hosting. I am hosting on my machine so when I go to localhost it still gives same 101 error.

Any ideas?

I'm getting the standard: Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

Update: I am using wordpress MU with domain mapping and I am hosting on my local machine so my IP address changes frequently. I have not changed it within Domain mapper.

I can't even access it locally using `http://localhost`.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the plugins?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I restarted the webserver and made sure the DNS was pointing to my ip.

Restarting the web server (httpd) seems to have worked as I could not access `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it from a different computer. Error 101 usually is a client side browser issue.

If Chrome:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117804

Comment: Yeah it isn't client side, does not work from other computers...and other sites I am hosting (non wordpress) work

Answer (score 0):

I today experienced this problem today too and the system engineer was telling that it was an error in the code. But for some reason i couldn't believe it. So i started my investigation:

- The DNS was resolving right (use nslookup or dig on the client)
- The browser could not find the page giving an "Connection was reset" error, so something at the server is not right.
- I opened up the Mozilla Network Inspector in my browser and i noted something remarkable: when i tried to open the website i sent a request to the server, but the server did not respond back to my browser. So this confirms it is really something with the server. Else i would at least get a 200/403/404/501 HTTP response.
- I renamed the .htaccess and all plugin folders of Wordpress so that Wordpress could not load them anymore. No result.
- I checked if a file on the website was accessable via direct request, and it was. So i created a phpinfo.php with as content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and looked up the memory_limit and post_size limits. Having these set to the default 32M/64M could lead to such problems. It was set much, much higher (512MB). So also this was not the cause.

After a while of searching something popped up in my mind: when you can't find a logical reason for the cause, just restart the services and retry again. Probably a service is partially crashed and is not catched by some error mechanisme. It is just like Microsoft Windows which you have to reboot regulary when you are experiencing problems with hardware or newly installed software.

So i asked the engineer to restart the Apache / httpd daemon and what do you think? Everything worked fine again. Like nothing really happened at all.

Possible commands for restarting the HTTP daemon as root:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
/etc/init.d/apache restart
```

Or via:

```
service apache2 restart
service httpd restart
service apache restart
```

Hope this helps some folks!

Answer (score 0):

Try manually resetting your plugins (no Dashboard access required). If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

If that does not resolve the issue, access your server via SFTP or FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel, navigate to /wp-content/themes/ and rename the directory of your currently active theme. This will force the default theme to activate and hopefully rule-out a theme-specific issue (theme functions can interfere like plugins).